# Generate multiple HTTP request from list values

Tags: python

I have a list with three hashes and the script should create HTTP request for each hash in the list and then save the file of the hash.
for some reason, the script generates only one HTTP request and for this reason, I manage to download only one file instead of three.

```
all_hashes = ['07a3355f81f0dbd9f5a9a', 'e0f1d8jj3d613ad5ebda6d', 'dsafhghhhffdsfdd']
for hash in all_hashes:
    params = {'apikey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'hash': (hash)}
    response = requests.get('https://www.test.com/file/download', params=params)
    downloaded_file = response.content

name = response.headers['x-goog-generation']

if response.status_code == 200:
        with open('%s.bin' % name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your response checking and saving code should also be in the loop
e.g

```
all_hashes = ['07a3355f81f0dbd9f5a9a', 'e0f1d8jj3d613ad5ebda6d', 'dsafhghhhffdsfdd']
for hash in all_hashes:
    params = {'apikey': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'hash': (hash)}
    response = requests.get('https://www.test.com/file/download', params=params)
    downloaded_file = response.content

    name = response.headers['x-goog-generation']

    if response.status_code == 200:
            with open('%s.bin' % name, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(response.content)
```

currently you `response` is the *last* request since your code is executed after the loop is finished.